# Consult mailbox_folder Error (FQL)

Tags: facebook-fql

I need to consult direct messages from a fan page, run the following FQL

```
https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=select folder_id from mailbox_folder where viewer_id = <my fanpage id>&access_token=<My page access token>
```

but the request return the next error:

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "(#606) You can only fetch messages for one user",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 606
   }
}
```

How to fix it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `conversations` endpoint in the Graph API

`/PAGE_ID/conversations`

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#conversations

I don't think there is an FQL equivalent for pages yet.